# In C++, how can I return a modified copy of the object without double copying it when overloading an operator?

Tags: c++, copy, operator-overloading

For a school project, I am writing a class to store arbitrary length integers. I have an operator- for it like this:

```
BigInt BigInt::operator-() const {
    BigInt newNum { *this };
    newNum.m_positive = !newNum.m_positive;
    return newNum;
}
```

The problem with this code is that the current object gets copied twice (at line 2 and line 4). Is there any way I can avoid this?

Things that don't work:

- Simply returning a reference to newNum: UB
- Allocating memory with new and returning a reference to it: memory leak
- Allocating memory and returning a (smart) pointer: Not the desired behavior for the - operator
- Changing this and have it copied by the return statement: Can't undo the changes to this

Comment: *The problem with this code is that the current object gets copied twice (at line 2 and line 4)* -- How do you know this?  The compiler's optimizer is smarter than you think it is.  Time to introduce you to the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)

Comment: And you've actually verified two copies are being made or are you just guessing?

Comment: This is untrue in modern C++17, only one copy is made.

Comment: And even before C++17, all major compilers were smart enough to reduce the number of copies made in "release mode".

Comment: *Things that don't work:* -- Well, hopefully we've saved you time on not having to worry about any of this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: *In C++, how can I return a modified copy of the object without double copying it when overloading an operator?* -- And the answer is a funny one -- *"don't do anything"*.   I know it sounds trivial, but that literally is the answer.

Comment: @Quimby Not _necessarily_, but it would be very surprising if NRVO didn't take effect here.

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered in the comments.
The code is optimized by the computer (within the boundaries of the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

What in particular happens here is copy-elision / return value optimization  as explained e.g. [here on tackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization).

Comment: @DumpQuestion It is good to close the question by accepting an answer. You could also [write the asnwer yourself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: You could also [write the answer yourself](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).